# ¿Cómo retornar un response en CSV o un archivo .csv?

Tags: python, django, csv, djangorestframework, restful

Estoy intentado que mi servicio rest con DRF me devuelva un archivo csv descargable. y me codigo es el siguiente :

```
class OperationsReportOrders(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == "POST": 
            #Aqui va toda la logica donde obtengo toda la data que necesito para mi csv y lo almaceno en file_rows

                    file_rows.append(row) # Creo file_rows donde se encuentra toda la data a escribir en csv
        #Escribo el archivo CSV
            with open('orders.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
                wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
                wr.writerows(file_rows)
        #Armo el response 
            csv_file = open('orders.csv', 'rb')
            response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(csv_file), content_type='text/csv')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % 'orders.csv'
            return response
        else:
            return Response("Metodo no autorizado", status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

Mi Defaul render class esta asi:

```
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',

    ),
```

Luego le agrego otro render:

```
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
            'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
            'rest_framework_csv.renderers.CSVRenderer',

    ),
```

y a mi clase le agrego:

```
renderer_classes = (r.CSVRenderer, )
```

pero al momento de hacer un request con con Content-Type igual  A text/csv Me retorna la siguiente:

```
{
    "detail": "Unsupported media type \"text/csv\" in request."
}
```

El request que hago al servicio es de la siguiente forma:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/csv"  -c cookies.txt -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/misuper/orders_reports/ -d '
    {
        {"date1":"02/12/2017",
        "date2":"03/12/2017",
        "shopper":null,
        "estado":null,
        "client":null
        }
    }'
```

Comment: ¿Estás enviando `text/csv` al hacer un request? No creo que eso sea necesario. Actualiza tu pregunta e incluye la forma en la que estás haciendo ese request.

Comment: he actualizado la pregunta, @César lo que necesito es que mi respuesta sea un CSV pero no se por que unicamente acepta request aplications/json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que estás un poco confundido, los [Renderers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#renderers) son para el response (la respuesta) y no para el request (la petición).

Django Rest Framework acepta JSON para las peticiones, por lo tanto, lo correcto es que incluyas `Content-Type: application/json` en la cabecera de tu comando `curl`:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -c cookies.txt -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/misuper/orders_reports/ -d '
    {
        {"date1":"02/12/2017",
        "date2":"03/12/2017",
        "shopper":null,
        "estado":null,
        "client":null
        }
    }'
```

Los datos que estás enviando están en formato JSON, no en CSV. Y me parece que solo deberías enviarlo de esta forma (sin los corchetes iniciales) para que sea un JSON válido:

```
{
    "date1": "02/12/2017",
    "date2": "03/12/2017",
    "shopper": null,
    "estado": null,
    "client": null
}
```

Es decir:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -c cookies.txt -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/misuper/orders_reports/ -d '
    {
        "date1": "02/12/2017",
        "date2": "03/12/2017",
        "shopper": null,
        "estado": null,
        "client": null
    }'
```

Comment: Gracias Cesar en realidad ahora me doy cuenta que eran los corchetes.